# how to implement multiple(for different game levels) leaderboard in android libgdx game?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am having 3 different game levels.So there would be three different high scores that need to be posted for Leaderboard on google play services. I dont understand this. what I did is that I have created a method

```
 public void submitScoreGPGS(int score);
 {
      Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),"id", score);
 }

 public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {             
      if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) 
      {
          startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), ""), 100);
      } 
      else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) 
      {
          loginGPGS();
      }
 }
```

For submitScore() I am simply calling this method on Game over at each level and sending High score from there.

But when I call  getLeaderboardGPGS() it only show the last level high score.

So I dont know how can I implement this multiple leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send score to multiple leaderboard there is a need to create all those multiple leaderboard and just send score to particular one.

To call all leaderboard at once on single button click use this

on `getleaderboard()`

```
startActivityForResult( Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent( gameHelper.getApiClient()), 1 );
```

. Might help somebody.

Answer (score 3):

You should create multiple leaderboards and use their different id's in your code. Something like this: (untested)

```
private static String LEADERBOARD0_ID = ""; 
private static String LEADERBOARD1_ID = ""; 

public void submitScoreGPGS(int score, int level);
{
    String id = "";
    if(level == 0)
        id = LEADERBOARD0_ID;
    else if(level == 1)
        id = LEADERBOARD1_ID;
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),id , score);
}

public void getLeaderboardGPGS() 
{             
  if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) 
  {
    String id = "";
    if(level == 0)
        id = LEADERBOARD0_ID;
    else if(level == 1)
        id = LEADERBOARD1_ID;
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id), 100);
  } 
  else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) 
  {
      loginGPGS();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir p.streef If I create multiple leaderboard Ids, can you tell me what should I do when I call them on leaderboard button? if I call `startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), LEADERBOARD0_ID), 100);` It only refers to ID _0.

Comment: You could have 3 buttons, 1 per level. Or dynamically use the id of the correct level.

    if(current_level == 0)
    {
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getAp‌​iClient(), LEADERBOARD0_ID), 100);
    }
    else if (current_level == 1)
    {
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getAp‌​iClient(), LEADERBOARD1_ID), 100);
    }
etc.